# Word for unnecessary good while being insufficient?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for something or somebody who fulfils the unnecessary while not fulfilling the necessary ?

Example: Matthew is a handsome thief.

It is good but not necessary that he is handsome, which he is, but it is necessary that is he not a thief, which he is.

Or for example, a car that is water-proof, which is good but unnecessary, while the velocity meter doesn't work, so the car doesn't meet the required demands even though it is water-proof.

Or for example, a product that looks nice (which is not necessary) and doesn't work good enough.

Or for example, a person who is nice or nice-looking (which is not necessary) while being dishonest and thus not fulfilling the necessary requirements while being more than necessary nice.

**Update**

Now I think that maybe a word for it could be *suboptimization* while not capturing the notion that you're actually failing the necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***superficially***, defined by [The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194305?redirectedFrom=superficially#eid)

> 3. As regards outward appearance or form, esp. as distinguished from inner reality; externally, on the surface; seemingly, apparently,
>      ostensibly. Also: on a cursory examination, at a glance

For your first and third examples:  Matthew is only superficially good husband material: he is good looking, but untrustworthy.

For your second example:  The car is superficially a good buy, but when you look under the hood, it is a different story.

Comment: This seems inapt. The request is for something positive that may be entirely evident and unnecessary (like the water-tightness of a car) co-existing with an unrelated fault (like the broken speedometer).  You've given a word that describes something that has the mere appearance of being positive that masks a related fault (like the husband who only pretends to be faithful).

Comment: @deadrat Now I think that maybe a word for it could be _suboptimization_ while not capturing the notion that you're actually failing the necessary.